# Disable insecure renegotiation in SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I wrote a webserver in .NET that supports HTTPS by using an `SslStream`.

Unfortunately, ssllabs.com outputs the following message about my implementation:

> This server is vulnerable to MITM attacks because it supports insecure renegotiation.

This links to an [interesting blog entry](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2009/11/05/ssl-and-tls-authentication-gap-vulnerability-discovered) about the vulnerability.

How do I disable renegotiation in .NET’s `SslStream`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SslStream uses SChannel.dll under the hood. You can configure which algorithms are available by modifying the registry:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030

In particular, the two entries highlighted in the following screenshot will disallow TLS renegotiation:

[image: regedit]

They are called `AllowInsecureRenegoClients` and `AllowInsecureRenegoServers`, are both DWORD values, both set to 0, and located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL`.

Apparently there is a hotfix you can install do disable insecure TLS/SSL renegotiation too (only applicable to Windows XP/Windows2003 server):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980436/en-us

Comment: The hotfix only applies to Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. The solution for me was to modify the registry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For window2012 it is not working with "AllowInsecureRenegoClients" and "AllowInsecureRenegoServers" are set to 0.

i have changed to AllowInsecureRenegoClients" as 0 and "DisableRenegoOnServer" as 1 and is working for me.