# Problems with SSL “insecure client renegotiation”; does Safari on OSX/iPad require insecurity?

Tags: windows, ssl, safari

I recently asked how to [disable SSL insecure renegotiation in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509928/disable-insecure-renegotiation-in-sslstream). I did this because [the ssllabs.com report for my site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=playkia.com) gives it an F rating “because it is vulnerable to MITM attacks because it supports insecure renegotiation”. Adding the registry entries fixed that.

However, now that I have added those registry entries, Safari on OS X and on iPad/iPhone no longer works. It fails with the following exception (.NET [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
Exception: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at RT.Servers.HttpServer.connectionHandler.<>c__DisplayClassf.<.ctor>b__e(IAsyncResult ar)
     -- Inner exception: Client's supplied SSPI channel bindings were incorrect (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
```

Safari then displays a page saying that it cannot load the website. Therefore, I changed the registry setting back for now and am still vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Can anything be done to fix both issues? Any suggestions are welcome, ranging from server settings to programming solutions.